Google Search Console: Sitemap could not be read
I have the following sitemap, at: https://techjobs.xyz/sitemap.xml
I submitted it earlier this week to Google, in Google Search Console, but it still says sitemap could not be read.


I've found some old Stack Overflow posts that say Google puts this message while it's indexing the site, but the state has been like this for many days, with no change.
The dashboard says "Aug 15, 2024" but I only resubmitted it today to see if that would fix the problem. I actually first submitted this sitemap a few days ago.
Is there some sort of issue with my sitemap? I've checked that it is valid XML many times. My robots.txt looks like this:
# https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: https://techjobs.xyz/sitemap.xml

Thanks for the help!

Has there been any update in Search Console since you posted this?

I've had this as well. Been uploading different sitemaps for the past week trying to figure out what the issue is. Basically just a few links now and still immediately shows 'Sitemap could not be read'

It actually appeared after a few weeks. You just have to give it some time

I have checked your sitemap https://techjobs.xyz/sitemap.xml
and it looks OK.
Go to Search Console and try deleting the sitemap and add it again. Then refresh the page.
